# Confused about voltage after rectification

Tags: voltage

I asked this question in 2016 and I am not altering the original question but want elaborate on what I did not understand then. 
I was working as a trainee at an electronic workshop and the teacher there was just an experienced tinkerer with no formal electronic education.

So my teacher belief was that the (-) is always GND and GND is not something that you can choose on your own. And I believed him. So that's why the confusion in the question.

"After AC voltage is passed through a bridge rectifier,   is there a negative voltage left or only ground and positive voltage."

After asking this question on this forum I learned that GND was indeed something that you can choose. After that I quit that JOB and instead went to Trade School to learn Electronics and now after three years I am working for a respectable company.
So thank you guys.

Comment: A bridge rectifier makes use of both the negative and positive voltages in order to produce DC.There remains an ac component,but it is positive.

Comment: For people like you who do not read the textbooks that explain these kinds of things, it's a 50/50 change you'll get either. The people that have studied bridge rectifiers can make the voltage the way they want it by connecting things properly.

Comment: Who's +ive ? You seem to think you just get "something". It is not like that. You get what you designed it for. You choose the ground reference then that is 0 V (by definition). The other node can be positive or negative depending on how you connect things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it really clear:

**Half wave rectification:**

Clips half the wave off.
[image]

**Full wave rectification (bridge:)**

Flips half the wave over so both are on one side.
[image]

[Images courtesy of the wikipedia recitifier page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier)

---

To answer the revised question:

What is ground and what is positive depends on your point of view.

Like this:

Typical full bridge:

(Note where I've placed the ground connection.)

[image]

Inverted ground:
(Look where the ground connection is, and what it does to the measured voltage.)

[image]

Comment: Then ask your question more clearly ! Although it's not what you asked, it does help in understanding ! Place a **ground** connection at the **bottom** side of resistor R, what will be the voltage on the **top** side ? Now place the ground on the **top** side, what will be the voltage at the bottom node ?

Comment: That was not what you were asking.

Answer (score 2):

The "negative" portion of the waveform is flipped over and superimposed on the "positive" portion (or the other way around, depending on how you look at it / wire it).

The negative voltage is still there, but inverted, and made positive. So you have waveform that is half the amplitude and (crudely) double the frequency (plus other frequency components added due to the distortion of the waveform).

Is there only "ground" and "positive" left over? Sure - if that's what you want to label them. You have two points of potential - one is higher than the other. If you want to label one as + and the other as GND then you can. Or you could label one as GND and the other as -. Or one as positive and one as more-positive.

There is no inherent "ground" as such - only what you choose to call ground is ground.

Answer (score 1):

If the transformer feeding the bridge rectifier has a center tap (connection to the center of the secondary winding), you can call that point Ground/Zero volts, then the circuit looks like two full-wave rectifiers, one producing a positive voltage, and the other producing a negative voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRrUh5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>